How to setup azure devops release sync pipeline so whenever conflict occurs it will throw conflict message failure
I have created one sync pipeline
Added one PowerShell task in that two branches are there so basically whenever any change merge to master branch i am trying to synch it into my feature branch. added below code into power shell.
git config --global user.email $(EmailAddress)
git status
git fetch "https://$(UserName):$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/gpb/g%20p%20b%20c/_git/gpb_c"
git checkout feature/pal/branchdev2
git pull origin feature/pal/branchdev2
git status
git checkout feature/pal/branchdev1
git pull origin feature/pal/branchdev1
git merge feature/pal/branchdev2
git status
git add .
git commit -m "push"
git push origin feature/pal/branchdev1
so here we can say feature/pal/branchdev2 this is my master branch so I will pull new changes from this and trying two merge into feature branch "feature/pal/branchdev1"
so whenever conflict occurs between two branches my pipeline fails with error
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

added screenshot as well enter image description here
in logs got
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md

so I wont to setting that whenever got conflict between two branches my pipeline fails with error conflict.
I have tried few settings options from PowerShell task enter image description here
but not able to throw error with specified option. please suggest a option so that pipeline will fail with conflict error.

You can redirect the merge error, and check the merge exit code, if it's not zero(conflict happens), use logging command to display the conflict details. Please check the error below, thanks.


but not able to throw error with specified option. please suggest a option so that pipeline will fail with conflict error.

You can redirect the merge error, and check the merge exit code, if it's not zero(conflict happens), use logging command Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]conflict error" to display the conflict details.
Details below:
# Attempt to merge and check if there is a conflict, redirect the message
git merge feature/pal/branchdev2 >> log

# If there is a conflict, the merge command will return a non-zero status, output the message on the log, and exit.
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]$(cat log)"
exit 1
}


No need to use the task settings, details below:


You can add the following lines to your PowerShell script to mark each Merge conflict file as an error message in the logs.
. . .

$isConflict = $false
$mergeResult = (git merge feature/pal/branchdev2)
foreach ($line in $mergeResult) {
  if ($line -match "CONFLICT") {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]$line"
    $isConflict = $true
  }
  else {
    Write-Host $line
  }
}
if ($isConflict) {
  exit 1
}

. . .


